# Sens du mot "gosse"

Tags: synonymes, québec

D'après ce que j'ai trouvé, le mot "gosse" en français signifie "enfant" (garçon ou fille). En français du Québec, il est synonyme (vulgaire) du mot "testicules" ("couilles"). Comment peut-on expliquer ce changement du sens ?

Comment: Je me rappelle très bien une discussion avec un ex-collègue québécois quelque peu récalcitrant à voir la photo de mes gosses que j'ai dans mon portefeuille ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les étymologies respectives de ces deux *[gosses](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gosse)* sont incertaines et rien ne prouve qu'ils dérivent d'une racine commune.

Pour le mot français qui est épicène, on trouve [gouspin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouspin), [gousse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gousse), l'occitan [gos](https://www.etymologie-occitane.fr/2011/09/gos-2/) voire une origine suédoise…

Pour le mot québécois, uniquement féminin, ce serait plutôt *[cosse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cosse)*.

Ce qui est tout de même notable, c'est que *[cosse](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C4425)* et *[gousse](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G1109)* ont des sens [voisins](https://www.redbubble.com/fr/i/carnet/mignon-2-petits-pois-dans-une-cosse-par-CuteCartoon/15581788.WX3NH).