# Quelle est l'origine du mot « glagne » ?

Tags: québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes, canada

Concernant les [*gosses*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/45256) en français du Québec, je lis au [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) qu'on avait il y a près d'un siècle, au Canada, *marbre* et *glagne*, de même sens :

[image]

<sup><sup>*Glossaire du parler français au Canada* (1930)</sup></sup>

Le mot *glagne* m'est complètement inconnu.

---

D'où vient ce mot et quel est le lien avec les *gosses* (testicules) ; en quoi la prononciation serait-elle differente de \glan\ ; quelqu'un le reconnaît-il ou l'emploie-t-il encore aujourd'hui ?

Answer (score 1):

Jamais entendu parler de *glagne* non plus.

Google ne trouve pas beaucoup d'occurrences. En voilà une qui est peut-être une piste :

> *Les glagnes ou testicules des rats-musqués, d'une odeur suave pendant le rût, sont réclamées par les dames de la cour pour parfumer leurs atours.*
> *Les lys et le lion en Amérique: Une guerre franco-anglaise 1534-1760*, Régine Marie Ghislaine Callaud-Belisle Hubert-Robert, 1980

Sinon, voici quelques hypothèses plus ou moins fantaisistes :

1. On reste dans les fruits et légumes comme pour cosse/gousse et il s'agit d'une déformation de *gland* :

[image]

2. Il pourrait aussi s'agir d'une déformation de *[glandes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33809/avoir-les-boules-submissive-or-aggressive)*.
3. Les deux mots commençant pas les mêmes lettres, y aurait-il un lien avec les *[glaouis](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/glaouis)* ? ;-)

Quant à la phonétique, le "n" avec un "◌̮" en dessous utilisé par le GPFC correspond à \ɲ\ donc la prononciation est \glaɲ\ qui rime avec *pagne* et pas avec *panne*.